# UpdateIssueForm.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'pk'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I tried making an update view using class-based views. I have not known how to pass this kwarg['pk'] to the view. I have ended up with an error. Here is the view and the form
View

```
class UpdateTeacherIssueView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = TeacherIssue
    form_class = UpdateTeacherIssueForm
    template_name = 'crud_forms/edit_teacher_issue.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_student') #To be changed
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateTeacherIssueView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['school'] = self.request.user.school
        kwargs['issuer'] = self.request.user
        #kwargs['pk'] = self.request.id
        return kwargs
```

The form

```
class UpdateTeacherIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Edit TeacherIssue Form"""
    def __init__(self,*args, pk, school,issuer, **kwargs):
        super(TeacherIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['issuer'].initial = issuer
        self.fields['book_id'].queryset = Books.objects.filter(school=school,no_of_books=1).select_related('subject')
        self.fields['borrower_teacher'].initial = pk
    class Meta:
        model = TeacherIssue
        fields = ['issuer','book_id','borrower_teacher','issue_date']
        widgets = {
            'borrower_teacher':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','type':'hidden'}),
            "issue_date":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            'issuer':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','type':'hidden'}),
            'book_id':Select2Widget(attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select Book','data-width': '100%'},)
        }
```

This is the error message

> UpdateTeacherIssueForm.**init**() missing 1 required positional
> argument: 'pk'

Answer (score 0):

your **init** function in ModelForm is not good:

```
    def __init__(self, pk, school,issuer,*args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateTeacherIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['issuer'].initial = issuer
        self.fields['book_id'].queryset = Books.objects.filter(school=school,no_of_books=1).select_related('subject')
        self.fields['borrower_teacher'].initial = pk
```

*args and **kwargs have to be placed at end of arguments function.
and In call of super you have to set the name of your current class.

You have to uncomment the `kwargs['pk'] = self.request.id`

Not sure if it is the problem: you do not show any error.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Uncommenting the kwargs['pk'} = self.request.id returns 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id'. I have the other suggestions you gave though.

Comment: 'id' is an url paramter ? You can access by `self.kwargs['id']` if you are write your url like this: `path('path/<int:id>/', UpdateTeacherIssueView.as_view())`